# Silverlight error - While creating Workbook object of interope excel

Tags: asp.net, wcf, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

Below error is coming while I create using below line from domain service.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook();


---------------------------
Error
---------------------------
Invoke operation 'CallExcel' failed. Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00020819-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

What is cause of this wierd error? If i do with word object then it works with interop too.

Comment: Are you calling this code from the Silverlight code running in the browser, or from the server? Are you certain that the end user has Office installed and in the correct version?

Comment: Silverlight does not has `Interop` interfaces, but AutomationFactory with `dynamic` objects. So, this is a server side code :)

Comment: I have one other problem that, When I run/open word document template file using WCF, It works fine. (Note: word template file consists of macro). But when I open any word file which consists of macro (Macro with dialog selection). Silverlight page hangs because, WCF service opens that macro dialog on server end. If I run application locally then works fine and also opens macro dialog on local environment. What can I do for this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u should create excel app. first.
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173186%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Yes, Thanks - I thought the same and did it that way.